# opencart tar backup via comand line on 1and1 dedicated server

Tags: backup, opencart, tar, server

Anyone know how to do an opencart tar backup using ssh/command line on a dedicated server?

I have tried searching everything and cannot find any information for this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To backup your site's files...

`tar czf opencart.tgz /path/to/opencart/`

Also adding database backup here for good measure...

`mysqldump -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD DATABASENAME > backup.sql`

(replacing the words in capitals... obviously!)